# Как столбцы в JTable заполнить данными из нескольких ArrayList

Tags: java

По нажатию кнопки создаются несколько `ArrayList<Integer>`, далее производятся расчеты и результаты записываются в эти `ArrayList`. Нужно каждый `ArrayList` вывести в отдельный столбец таблицы (`JTable`). Подскажите, как это сделать, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**enSO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973577/create-jtable-with-arraylist) - дописываете функцию, которая кидает ArrayList/массив

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Test {

    private static ArrayList<String> rowA = new ArrayList();
    private static ArrayList<String> rowB = new ArrayList();
    private static ArrayList<String> rowC = new ArrayList();
    private static ArrayList<String> titel = new ArrayList();
    private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> table = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        titel.add("Column 1");
        titel.add("Column 2");
        titel.add("Column 3");

        addRows("I", "dont", "want");
        addRows("to", "search", "by");
        addRows("myself", "a simple", "question");


        table.add(rowA);
        table.add(rowB);
        table.add(rowC);

        Object[] tempTitel = titel.toArray();
        String[][] tempTable = new String[table.size()][];
        int i = 0;
        for (List<String> next : table) {
            tempTable[i++] = next.toArray(new String[next.size()]);
        }

        JTable EndTable = new JTable(tempTable,tempTitel);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(EndTable));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void addRows(String rowa, String rowb, String rowc) {
        rowA.add(rowa);
        rowB.add(rowb);
        rowC.add(rowc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но вывод получается в строку а не в столбец. И фрейм и таблицу создавать не нужно они уже есть готовые.

Comment: В какую строку вывод? `addRows("I", "dont", "want")` добавляет столбец в таблицу. Фрейм и таблица создавалась для тестов - теперь сами вертите и крутите.